# get a value of textview from first activity and checked the textview value into toggle button automatically of another activity

Tags: android

First Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(InvestmentDetail_Activity.this, InvestmentUpdate_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("Interval", Iinterval); //integer value
startActivity(intent);
```

Second activity

```
if (I_interval != null) {          
    I_interval=Integer.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("Interval"));
}
if (I_interval != null) {
            switch (I_interval) {
                case 1:
                    toggleOne.setChecked(true);
                    due_time_int = 1;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    toggleThree.setChecked(true);
                    due_time_int = 3;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    toggleSix.setChecked(true);
                    due_time_int = 6;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    toggleTwelve.setChecked(true);
                    due_time_int = 12;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }//code is not working
```

Comment: Please provide more input to your problem.

Comment: make text view static so that you can access it in another activity and do your stuff or use interface to achieve it .

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you are passing `Integer` value from `intent`

```
intent.putExtra("Interval", Iinterval); //integer value
```

So, **You need to Change this**

```
I_interval=Integer.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("Interval"));
```

**to**

```
I_interval=Integer.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra("Interval"));
```

Comment: Ok, let me check again

Comment: Can you update more code to your Question, its seems fine may be you make mistake in another things, So please add more code